# Most efficient way to check if a section has any active entries

Tags: entries, sections, query

Just wondering what the most efficient way to check whether a section has any entries or not. Based on this, I'm showing some content. The content doesn't take any information from the entries in the section, so it'll be a superfluous query no matter what.

For context, this is basically what it'll look like:

```
{% if craft.entries.section('whatever') | length > 0 %}
    <a href="www.com">Go here</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a definitive answer at all, but you could at least add a `.ids()` on that so it only retrieves the entry ids and not all the entry data...

```
{% if craft.entries.section('whatever').ids() | length > 0 %}
<a href="www.com">Go here</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Would this be better than doing `.section().first.id`?

Comment: `.section().first.id` will break if there is no ids.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `{{ craft.entries.section('whatever').total() }}` for that.

Comment: For some reason `.total()` is slower than `.limit(1) | length`, by ~10ms on average. And also this is only testing when there are 1 or 0 active entries.

Comment: That's a cool tip. Did you compare it to Jeremy's suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, that was about the same as `.limit(1) | length`, so actually faster than `total()`